# Is higher number of different folders affecting website load speed?

Tags: html, performance, web, pagespeed

I have one question about page load speed. Consider a case when I have different kinds of images on my web page, such as icons, logos, images inside content etc....

I want to know whether having separate folders for each media category may affect the page load speed:

```
/logos
/icons
/images
```

Will the webpage load faster if the images of all categories were located in a single folder rather in multiple ones?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though performance-related questions often get closed due to them not being answerable without benchmarks on the machine, this one is worth an answer since unless you run a potato-based computer, you won't have any performance impact.

Directories are not actually physical folders like you would have in real life.
They are simply registers of pointers to disk spaces where your files are stored. *(Of course this is massively over-simplified as it involves file-systems and more low-level stuff, but that's not needed at that point).*

To come back to your question, the difference between loading two files from two directories:

```
/var/foobar/dir1/image1.jpeg
/var/foobar/dir2/image2.jpeg
```

or one directory:

```
/var/foobar/dir1/image1.jpeg
/var/foobar/dir1/image2.jpeg
```

...is that your file system will have to look-up two different directories tables. With modern file-systems and moderate (even low-end) hardware, this causes no issues.

As @AjitZero mentioned, here your performance impact will come from the size of the files, the number of distinct HTTP requests (i.e.: How many images, CSS, scripts, etc...) and the way you cache data on the user's computer.

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, I got the logic. Stay safe

Answer (score 0):

No, the number of folders doesn't affect the speed of page-load.

Lesser number of HTTP requests matter, however, so you can use sprite sheets.